# Set focus on postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a Booking Form in a webform on my website.

3 options have autopostback enabled.  Problem is when one is triggered, the page reloads from the top.

How to reload from the option that did the postback?

I'm sure there's an easy solution to this?

Regards
Tea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx) to `true`.

1. You can set it programmatically

   ```
   Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
   ```
2. In the page declaration

   ```
   <%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
   ```
3. Or in the web.configs `<system.web>` section.

   ```
   <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
   ```

Another option is to use asynchronous postbacks for example with the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit. Then only certain areas are reloaded with javascript and not the whole page.

Comment: Will it also set focus? Can't find anything mentioning this in the docs.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, use `Control.Focus()`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178232(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use session variables to do that.

inside the event that is triggered by the postback control, do something like

```
session('Focused_Control') = sender;
```

then when you want to return focus to the control after the postback

```
Option myOption = session('Focused_Control');
myOption.Focus();
```